# Gtk::Label update label speed

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtk, gtkmm

I have a program that tries to update a Gtk::Label at a very high frequency, and is exhibing very unstable behaviour. I get several of these errors:

```
(gtkWindow:26559): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_copy: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (src)' failed

(gtkWindow:26559): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed

(gtkWindow:26559): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_pixel_extents: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(gtkWindow:26559): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

until the program eventually crashes with:

```
Pango:ERROR:pango-layout.c:3916:pango_layout_check_lines: assertion failed: (!layout->log_attrs)
```

2921
    Aborted (core dumped)

The relevant code lines:

```
while(1){
    std::string sensorLine="";
    _serial.readLine(&sensorLine);         // read serial data with boost::asio
    _output->set_label(sensorLine.data()); // _output -> Gtk::Label*
    std::cout<<sensorLine<<std::endl;
    //sleep(1);
}
```

I only get the error if I try to use `_output->setlabel`, if I comment this line everything  runs smoothly, with the output printed in the console. The same thing happens if I call `sleep()`inside the loop, the `Gtk::Label` is updated as the commandline and no errors are thrown. 
This loop is running on a separate thread that receives _output as argument.

Comment: Seriously, do sanity checking on data you feed to `set_label`. It needs to be null terminated...

Comment: doesn't `std::string` already has that kind of checks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `g_idle_add` (which actually *is* threadsafe) with a callback which in turn actually modifies (read: calls `set_label` on) your `GtkLabel`.

---

**Do not call UI functions from a different thread! Never ever!** You open the box of pandora if you do.

Comment: So I should discard my separate thread at all? Or pass the data to `g_idle_add` first and then call `set_label`?

Comment: That depends if the IO to your sensor is long blocking or not.  If it is a long operation (couple of 10s of `ms`) use a seperate thread (loop and use `g_idle_add`), if not you can use `g_timeout_add` and do the sensor read in the callback.

Comment: right now I am using a `g_idle_add` call back to read from a shared `std::string*` that is update by my separate thread, I am getting several segmentation faults and Glib errors.

Comment: Well, you are accessing potentially changing data from 2 different threads. That will break. Copy the data, just a `g_memdup` and `g_free`. Also showing some more code would really help (minimal compileable example).

Comment: I had a similar issue where I was updating statusbar from within another thread - not doing this status update removed the critical error messages - however, how can I safely make an update to my statusbar from within the thread???